# Shiny Select different data frames through selectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I'm building a shiny app to select values from several data frames using `selectizeInput`. But I'm kind of stuck at the middle. Below is my sample code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
A <- read.csv(.............)
B <- read.csv(.............)
C <- read.csv(.............)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(12, 
                    hichartOutput("BAR"))
             ),

    selectizeInput('WhichOne', 'Select One', 
                   choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                   selected = 'all')
```

server.R

```
output$BAR <- renderHighchart({
    mydata <- input$WhichOne

    hc <- highchart() %>%
       hchart(mydata, 'bar', hcaes(x = ok, y = LikePercent))
```

So basically, my highchart will depend on which data frame users select.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Without a reproducible example, it is hard to help you. But this could help you started:

```
data_sets <- list(A, B, C)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose a dataset:', choices = c("A" = "1", "B" = "2", "C" = "3")),
  highchartOutput('my_plot')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  datasetInput <- reactive({
    temp <- data.frame(data_sets[[as.numeric(input$dataset)]])
  }) 

  output$my_plot <- renderHighchart({
    mydata <- datasetInput()

    hc <- highchart() %>%
      hchart(mydata, 'bar', hcaes(x = ok, y = LikePercent))

    hc
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you MLavoie! It struggles me for a long time, and your solution helps!

Comment: @M.zz.M If it helps you, you can accept the answer!